# Returning a char pointer when the argument is a constant char pointer

Tags: c, linux, constants

For an exercise in school, I was asked to implement the functions

```
 char *index(const char *s, int c);
 char *rindex(const char *s, int c);
```

Which I didn't feel like I had any trouble with until I compiled with the compiler flags the
instructor outlined us to put into our makefile, then it wouldn't compile because I was using
a non-constant pointer to point at a character in a string that was constant.

It makes sense that you shouldn't be able to assign a non-constant pointer the address of a constant pointer since it defeats the purpose of the const keyword being there in the first place.

What I don't understand is how the function is supposed to return a pointer to the the first/last occurrence
of the character c in the string when the return is not a const char.

I adjusted my functions to work with the `const char*` argument, but returning is impossible without changing the return type which I can't do because the prototype is supposed to be the same as the actual `index` and `rindex` functions in C.

I guess my question is, how do these functions return a pointer to a character in a constant string without themselves being a `const char*`?

Comment: Were you given the function signatures or came up with these yourself? Because the naming suggests that it is supposed to return numerical index rather than pointer to a specific character.

Comment: The function prototypes were given by the instructor and they match the function prototypes for the index and rindex functions implemented in one of the C libraries.

Comment: You can return a non-const pointer to a char in a string pointed to by a const char pointer... if you ignore warning, as this can lead to undefined behavior, but it will compile. If you're being forced to compile with `-Werror` (or equivalent) then you can't.

Comment: In [index, rindex](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rindex) it notes that [strchr](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strchr.html) and [strrchr](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strrchr.html) defined in `string.h` are preferred.

Comment: They are making me use -Werror which now confuses me as to what my instructor is expecting. Thanks. I'll just have to email them about their inconsistent expectations

Comment: What is the lesson being taught? If it is to learn about the pitfals of mixing const and non-const pointers, and what backwards compatibility needs to be implemented (eg, in libraries like glibc), even as standards change, the question is completely valid. This broken specification for the `index` and `rindex` functions must be implemented in a sane way, and it must work as expected. glibc had to do a lot of dancing to make it happen. Maybe the point is to learn about those dance moves.

Answer (score 5):

The prototypes are designed this way so the functions can be called with pointers to `char` as well as pointers to `const char`. `index` and `rindex` are ancient BSD names for the standard library functions `strchr` and `strrchr`. `strstr` works the same, returning a `char *` but taking 2 `const char *` arguments.

The upcoming C23 Standard attempts to fix this issue with a new *generic* approach for the standard functions `memchr`, `strchr`, `strpbrk`, `strrchr`, `strstr` that will be defined as returning a pointer with the same `const` qualification as their first argument. C++ uses overloading to achieve this more explicitly.

You can *force* the compiler to accept returning a `const char *` with an explicit `(char *)` cast.

Some compilers will still issue a warning about removing the `const` qualification. To disable this warning, you can use an intermediary cast as `(uintptr_t)` defined in `<stdint.h>`, introduced in C99 as an optional integer type that has the same size as character pointers. Support for `uintptr_t` can be detected by testing if `UINTPTR_MAX` is defined.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

char *index(const char *s, int c) {
    char cc = (char)c;
    for (;;) {
        if (*s == cc) {
#ifdef UINTPTR_MAX
            return (char *)(uintptr_t)s;
#else
            return (char *)s;
#endif
        }
        if (*s++ == '\0') {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `uintpir_t` was introduced in C99.

Comment: Re "*Some compilers will still issue a warning about removing the `const` qualification.*", Example? Neither [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/qfnTcjxa1) nor [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/4MxdjxMME) do with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: @ikegami: **clang -Weverything** enables **-Wcast-qual**, which does complain about explicit `const` removal.

Comment: The `index()` and `rindex()` functions were in 7th Edition Unix before they were in BSD.  System V introduced `strchr()` and `strrchr()` as replacements with the more systematic `str` prefix.

Answer (score 4):

Simply cast the pointer to `char *` when returning it, as in `return (char *) p;`.

When an object is defined with `const`, the C standard does not define what happens if a program tries to modify the object. However, when a pointer is declared to point to a `const` type, the qualifier merely serves as an advisory. It denotes how the pointer is intended to be used and provides diagnostic messages if it is used inappropriately without a cast. When a cast is used, compilers will typically allow the conversion without a diagnostic.

A function parameter is commonly declared to point to a `const`-qualified type to indicate that the function itself will not modify objects through that pointer. However, if the function needs to return a pointer to a non-`const`-qualified type, it can cast the pointer to the desired type.

In C, you may take a pointer to an object that was defined without `const`, convert it to a pointer to a `const`-qualified type (as happens automatically when passing it for a parameter of that type), manipulate the pointer (such as performing pointer arithmetic with it), and convert it back to the original type without `const`. This has defined behavior according to the C standard (in the absence of anything else that would have undefined behavior).

The need to perform this cast is a deficiency in the C language. The `const` qualifier was developed late, after the bulk of the language was established, and there is no mechanism to indicate that a pointer points to an object that is not `const` but that we want to treat the pointer as pointing to `const` temporarily. We can see this in the standard C library: The `strchr` routine has a parameter of type `const char *` and returns a pointer to a character in the pointed-to string, and that pointer has type `char *`. Internally, the `strchr` routine must convert a `const char *` to a `char *`.

Comment: "there is no mechanism to indicate that a pointer points to an object that is not const but that we want to treat the pointer as pointing to const temporarily"  This old language flaw is about to get fixed in C23, at least as far as standard library functions go. `strchr` will for example become `QChar *strchr (QChar *s, int c);`, where `QChar*` is a special type which will ensure that the returned type has the same qualifiers as the passed type.

Comment: @Lundin: There is no actual `QChar` type. That is just used in the documentation to describe the library “functions”. The “functions” are actually macros, intended to be implemented using `_Generic` to detect whether types with qualifiers are used. The standard notes the actual underlying function returns a pointer to an unqualified element. When used with an argument of type “pointer to qualified type”, the macro casts the return value to a pointer to a qualified element.

Answer (score 3):

Cast the pointer

For example, replace

```c
return s + i;
```

with

```c
return (char *)( s + i );
```

Reasoning follows.

---

It would be ideal if this `index` could be used on both constant strings

```c
const char *s1 = ...;
const char *s1b = index( s1, .. );
```

and on non-constant strings

```c
char *s2 = ...;
char *s2b = index( s2, .. );
```

Before generics, the only way that can happen (without extra work on the caller's side) is if the parameter is a `const char *` and the return value is a `char *`. This is why `index` was declared as

```c
char *index( const char *s, int c );
```

To achieve this, you'll need a cast in the function.

```c
return (char *)( s + i );
```

As a consequence, the following error isn't detected at compile-time:

```c
const char *s3 = ...;
char *s3b = index( s3, .. );
*s3b = 0;  // XXX Undefined behaviour
```

But that's an acceptable compromise for a more useful `index`.

As hinted above, this compromise is no longer necessary with generics. But those are relatively new.

Answer (score 2):

There are two lessons your instructor is teaching you about C:

1. A `const char *` argument doesn't mean the string is constant, but that the function **promises to not modify it**.
2. **Casting** to a non-const pointer is necessary and must be done to satisfy the return type in the required signature.

Comment: ```const char*``` is located in ```read only``` section of your data and it is indeed a pointer to constant characters. You cannot modify its characters unless you cast it to ```char*```

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh: no, not necessarily. It's perfectly valid to pass to index a pointer to stack or heap-allocated (hence writeable) data. As an argument, const only requires the called function to not write the buffer.

Comment: @JaredoMills You're right on that point, but returning a `char *` also means that eventually you can modify the value pointed by after the call, and this may not be possible in all cases.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès the specification (signature) is not up for the student asker to modify. He must implement what the specification says. I agree with you that the specification is not great; this is because the `const` keyword was a late addition to C, and it's not possible in C to specify that a buffer is read only. Because the language is what it is, it's up to the programmer to do the right thing. It's the same as malloc/free - up to the programmer to not leak memory; the language lacks many safety mechanisms.

Comment: @JaredoMills Sure, I did not wanted to ask OP to change anything, just to inform him that this interface is wrong at some place.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *index(const char *s, int c);
char *rindex(const char *s, int c);
```

Since nobody mentioned the elephant in the room yet: if these functions are to return a pointer into the passed data `s`, then ***this is a badly designed function API***. Your teacher is teaching you bad program design for some strange reason and you should really ask them why. Correctly designed functions face two choices:

- Either the function is not to modify the contents, in which case returning a `const char*` might be sensible.
- Or otherwise, if there is reason to believe that either the function or the caller needs to modify the data, `const` shouldn't be used.

We should never design functions that may have to rely on casts from `const char*` to `char`. "Casting away `const`" is always very fishy and a clear indication of bad design.

For example, suppose someone passes a pointer to actual read-only data to the function, like a string literal. Casting away `const` might mean that someone will do a write access later on, either intentionally or by accident, in which case the code would invoke undefined behavior.

This well-known design flaw crept into the C standard library itself back in the days, so some functions like `strstr` or `strchr` are broken by design (but will finally get fixed 40 years later in upcoming C23).